# Find force centroid from forces and moments

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, linear-algebra

> A force $\vec F = (F_x,F_y,F_z)$ is applied to a point that its position vector is $\vec r = (x,y,z)$ generating a moment $\vec M = (M_x,M_y,M_z)$. Find position vector of the point ($\vec r$) if $\vec F$ and $\vec M$ are known.

I know that,

$$\vec M=\vec r\times \vec F$$

However, how can we solve for $\vec r$ in terms of $\vec M$ and $\vec F$? i.e. How is the system above solved for $x,y,z$?

Comment: There is only a unique solution if $P$ and $F$ are orthogonal. See [What's the opposite of a cross product?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32600/whats-the-opposite-of-a-cross-product).

Answer (score 1):

A *moment or torque,* ***M,*** vector is defined as cross product of *position,* ***P,*** and *force,* ***F,*** vectors. So, you need first to calculate this cross product *parametrically* (even though your position vector, namely ***P*** is not given). And then, equate this cross product to the given *moment* which is given as ***M.*** You should be able to match the two sides component-by-component to figure out what is ***P.***